# Passing param through form cakePHP 2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I am in a view (view/1) and i want to pass a param to one of my functions on its controller.

I have tried this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('action' => 'move'));
```

But then, it doesn't pass the param $id which is on the URL.

I have seen it works well on the edit view just doing this:

```
 echo $this->Form->create('Post');
```

Why is it not working with my view / controller function?

Also, if i try to pass them with something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('action' => 'move', 1));
```

It prints something like this:

```
<form action="/posts/move" 1="1"
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this can help http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1383/Form

Comment: No, it doesn't help :) I have already took a look at 2.2 documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the argument, you can simply pass the param in action as:-

> echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('action' => 'move/1'));

In Controller,

> debug($this->request->params['pass'][0]);

Since edit view already contains the id of the post being edited, we don't need to do explicitly pass the id in form create.

Comment: The view 'view' also contains the id of the post to being edited. Can't I do something similar? This way seems a bit harcoded :)

Comment: if you have the id at the url already, why do you need to pass it from the form? Cakephp can retrieve that url from the request->params. Can you clarify more on this.

Comment: Its on the view: www.mysite.com/view/4  but i can not create a form with it like it happends on the edit form. I can not create something like <form action="/posts/move/1" using the Form helper without having to use the "url" option.

Comment: it should work, 'action' => 'move/1' in the Form helper must generate the required action....

Comment: Yeah, but.. there's no other way? Is it the correct one? Seems a bit out from CakePHP syntax.

Comment: Probably not the best way to go about this... See my response below

Answer (score 1):

Pass it in Cake style:)

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('action' => array( 'action' => 'move', 1 ) ));
```

-or-

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('url' => Router::url( array( 'action' => 'move', 1 ) ) ));
```

That will accomplish it while taking routing into account.